# Alter a BLOB field in Database

Tags: c#, sqlite, blob

I've got a BLOB column in a sqlite databasefile an I want to alter this field to give it more information.

The BLOB contains this text:

> "{\"Number\":\"35\",\"ChannelType\":\"TV\",\"ServiceName\":\"DVBLink\",\"ImageInfos\":[],\"IsInMixedFolder\":false,\"Name\":\"13th Street HD\",\"Id\":\"466ab1fb9be4f77e65ad2b229a15c326\",\"DateCreated\":\"2015-09-14T12:55:51.4081476Z\",\"DateModified\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z\",\"DateLastSaved\":\"2015-10-17T13:34:37.4214116Z\",\"LockedFields\":[],\"ParentId\":\"00000000000000000000000000000000\",\"Studios\":[],\"Genres\":[],\"ProviderIds\":{\"ProviderExternalId\":\"13250000\"}}"

Here the code to get this information

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=D:\\2work\\VisualStudio\\Projects\\MapTVIcons\\library.db");

            con.Open();

            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();

            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT guid,data FROM TypedBaseItems where type = 'MediaBrowser.Controller.LiveTv.LiveTvChannel'";
            //cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TypedBaseItems";

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
            ds.Tables.Add("TypedBaseItems");
            da.Fill(ds);
            //dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
           foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[1].Rows)
            {


                byte[] array = (byte[])dr["data"];
                var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(array);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is readout the Id value (inside the blob Id\":\"466ab1fb9be4f77e65ad2b229a15c326) and add a path to the "ImageInfos" and put the new BLOB back to the database file.

Comment: Use update statement then.

Comment: You would need to be able to uniquely identify each row that you want to alter - maybe by primary key, so modify query to get id field & data  - & use an SQL UPDATE command as @TechieBee said.

Comment: sorry, I for the missunderstanding I meant the id inside the blob: Id\":\"466ab1fb9be4f77e65ad2b229a15c326\

Comment: Where are you stuck? updating the JSON blob or writing it back to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A not-so-short way of doing this would be to extend on what you have already tried:

1. Read json blob in a C# object (Include Newtonsoft.Json nuget package in your project)

   ```
       var json = "JSON STRING";

       var ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
   ```
2. Above will translate into following C# classes

   ```
   public class ProviderIds
   {
       public string ProviderExternalId { get; set; }
   }


   public class RootObject
   {
   public string Number { get; set; }

   public string ChannelType { get; set; }
   public string ServiceName { get; set; }
   public List<object> ImageInfos { get; set; }
   public bool IsInMixedFolder { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string DateCreated { get; set; }
   public string DateModified { get; set; }
   public string DateLastSaved { get; set; }
   public List<object> LockedFields { get; set; }
   public string ParentId { get; set; }
   public List<object> Studios { get; set; }
   public List<object> Genres { get; set; }
   public ProviderIds ProviderIds { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. And then you can simply manipulate the fields you like.
4. And update it back to the database

Comment: .. and write it back to the database

Comment: So far so good, I created two classes ProviderIDs and RootObject like point 2 . And call this `                    byte[] array = (byte[])dr["data"];

                    string str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(array);
                    JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    RootObject retObject = (RootObject)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(str);`

Comment: which result in the Error: +  $exception {"Object of Type \"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]\"  cannot be converted to type \"MapTVIcons.RootObject\" } System.InvalidCastException

Comment: This is working: **                    RootObject retObject = (RootObject)json_serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(str);**

Comment: @user1073472 Change the convert method, please get the updated code, and it works fine in my console app.

Comment: Yes, but I've now no Ideas to point 4. OK I have to write an update comment with guid as key, but with what data blob do I have to update ?

Comment: @user1073472 Well, that should be a simple Update operation. Have a look here http://lamahashim.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/c-read-insert-update-delete-from-sql.html

Comment: Thank you, I figured out that ImageInfos is a new class with strings "Path", "Type" and "DateModified" which I have create and change "RootObject" to public ImageInfos ImageInfos { get; set; }

Comment: Now this error: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'MapTVIcons.ImageInfos' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path 'ImageInfos', line 1, position 72.

Comment: I found it, I had to say List<ImageInfos> inside the RootObjects, now everything works fine, thank you